# Using safeargs to create deep links

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-safe-args

I am creating an explicit deeplink to a fragment in my app (Navigation component). This is how I am currently doing it:

```
val args = bundleOf(
    "roomId" to roomId,
    "receiver" to receiver
)
return NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph_home)
    .addDestination(R.id.navigation_chat_private)
    .setArguments(args)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

The arguments are defined in the nav_graph like this:

```
<argument android:name="roomId" app:argType="string" />
<argument android:name="receiver" app:argType="integer" />
```

This works without issue. But I can't help but wonder if there is a way to avoid hardcoding the parameter names twice. I feel like there HAS to be a better way. Something along the lines of:

```
val chatArgs = NavigationChatPrivateArgs(roomId,receiver)
return NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph_home)
    .addDestination(R.id.navigation_chat_private)
    .setArguments(chatArgs.toBundle())
    .createPendingIntent()
```

But there is no such constructor in the generated safeArgs class. I also tried calling the empty constructor and then setting the values, but the args are `val`s, so cannot be reassigned. Is anybody aware of an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Every args definitely allows you to construct it in full completely manually with exactly the expected code you've included if you've generated your Safe Args in Kotlin (using the `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` plugin). Are you generating Kotlin Safe Args code or generating Java Safe Args code (using the `androidx.navigation.safeargs` plugin)?

Comment: Yes. That was it. I switched to the kotlin safeargs plugin and it worked. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Safe Args plugin to generate Kotlin code via the `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` plugin, each Args class is given a constructor that uses arguments for required arguments and [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments) for parameters that have a `defaultValue` or that are `nullable`.

This lets you generate exactly the code you've posted:

```
val chatArgs = NavigationChatPrivateArgs(roomId,receiver)
val bundle = chatArgs.toBundle()
```

However, when you generate Java code via the `androidx.navigation.safeargs` plugin, default arguments are not available. Therefore the Java code uses a [builder pattern](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/builder-design-pattern-in-java) - you construct a `NavigationChatPrivageArgs.Builder` instance, which takes required arguments as constructor parameters for the `Builder` class and optional parameters as additional setters available on the `Builder` and then call `build()` on the `Builder` to construct the class.

```
// Assuming both parameters are required
val chatArgs = NavigationChatPrivateArgs.Builder(roomId,receiver).build()
val bundle = chatArgs.toBundle()
```

So in all cases, yes, you can directly create your Args class exactly for use in cases like this or in tests.